# Nested query for getting distinct category and there associated sub-category Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I am working on laravel code, i am finding difficulty in getting nested query for sub-category list. My table structure is, column name below

```
id | category_name       |  cat_head
1  |  ultra slim suit    |  suit
2  |  slim suit          |  suit
3  |  Shoes              |  shoes
4  |  Hats               |  accessories
5  |  Cufflinks          |  accessories
```

i want cat_head as main menu and category_name under it.
Kindly help me in laravel eloquent way.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two tables like `heads` and `categories` and you can define `one-to-many` relationship between these tables. So, your table should look like this:

**heads table**

```
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  | cat_head | timestamps |
+-----+----------+------------+
```

**categories table**

```
+-----+---------------+---------+------------+
| id  | category_name | head_id | timestamps |
+-----+---------------+---------+------------+
```

Now, to define relationships between these tables, you have to create two models:

**Head Model**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categorie');
}
```

**Categorie Model**

```
public function head()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Head');
}
```

Then, in the controller, you can do something like this:

```
$menu = Head::with('categories')->get();
```

Hope this helps.